# When importing data, column names are not verified

Tags: database, copy, cnosdb

I think that by default, the csv file and column names should be verified to be consistent. But cnosdb doesn't seem to do this? Or is there a problem with my operation?

### 0. Env

```
version: cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 721266b
mode: single
```

### 1. Reproduce step

#### 1.1 Create table

```
public ❯ CREATE TABLE air (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (now(), 'XiaoMaiDao2', 56, 69, 411);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (now(), 'XiaoMaiDao3', 56, 69, 411);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (now(), 'XiaoMaiDao4', 56, 69, 411);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (now(), 'XiaoMaiDao1', 56, 69, 711);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (now(), 'XiaoMaiDao2', 56, 69, 711);
```

#### 1.2 Export data

```
public ❯ copy into 'test' from air file_format = (type = 'csv');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 6    |
+------+
```

#### 1.3 Import data

```
public ❯ CREATE TABLE air003 (visibility1 DOUBLE,temperature1 DOUBLE,pressure1 DOUBLE,TAGS(t1));
public ❯ copy into air003 from 'test' file_format = (type = 'csv');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 6    |
+------+
public ❯ select * from air003;
+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| time                       | t1          | visibility1 | temperature1 | pressure1 |
+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 2024-01-09T07:46:23.991997 | XiaoMaiDao3 | 56.0        | 69.0         | 411.0     |
| 2024-01-09T07:46:23.948910 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0        | 69.0         | 411.0     |
| 2024-01-09T07:46:23.995182 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0        | 69.0         | 711.0     |
| 2024-01-09T07:46:23.989805 | XiaoMaiDao2 | 56.0        | 69.0         | 411.0     |
| 2024-01-09T07:46:23.996498 | XiaoMaiDao2 | 56.0        | 69.0         | 711.0     |
| 2024-01-09T07:46:23.993600 | XiaoMaiDao4 | 56.0        | 69.0         | 411.0     |
+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```